# How can i use a pre loaded map in navigation stack?

Tags: navigation, mapping, ros-kinetic, 2d-mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm making a robot using RPi. I made a map using my hector_slam and rplidar on my laptop, so I have the pgm and yaml files (I was having some issue running hector_slam on RPi). How can I use it in the navigation stack. Do I need to create a map_server node and publish it? If yes, how should I do it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324727/how-can-i-use-a-pre-loaded-map-in-navigation-stack?/) by [sajal](https://answers.ros.org/users/41875/sajal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-06-05**:
This is all discussed in the Navigation Stack tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may use the map_server node at your launch file. Do not forget to upload  the.yaml file.

Something like this.

```
  <arg name="map_file" default="$(find robot_navigation)/maps/my_map.yaml"/>
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />
```

---

Originally posted by [Lucas Marins](https://answers.ros.org/users/38409/lucas-marins/) with karma: 71 on 2019-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0